# Jenkins MSBuild SonarQube Runner 1.0.2 projectinfo.xml file not found

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I'm having trouble running the sonarqube msbuild runner v1.0.2 in jenkins.
The build runs fine, but the plugin doesn't seem to import the sonar targets correctly.

Here's the logs when the sonar build kicks off:

```
[workspace] $C:\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MS_Build_Runner_1.0.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:my.project /n:myprojectname /v:1.0 /d:sonar.host.url=http://1.1.1.1:9000/ 
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Bootstrapper 1.0.2.0
Default properties file was found at C:\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MS_Build_Runner_1.0.2\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MS_Build_Runner_1.0.2\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Checking for updates...
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Pre-processor 1.0.2.0
10:17:18.025  Loading analysis properties from C:\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MS_Build_Runner_1.0.2\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
10:17:18.056  Updating build integration targets...
10:17:18.072  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
10:17:21.332  Generating rulesets...
Pre-processing succeeded.
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C " C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Development /t:Clean,Build /tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /m:1 /fl2 /flp2:verbosity=diagnostic myprojectname.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\.jenkins\jobs\Technology - WWW - Content Store Client\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C " C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Development /t:Clean,Build /tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /m:1 /fl2 /flp2:verbosity=diagnostic ContentStoreClientSolution.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.81.0...
```

And here when if finishes:

```
[workspace] $ C:\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MS_Build_Runner_1.0.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end 
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Bootstrapper 1.0.2.0
Default properties file was found at C:\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MS_Build_Runner_1.0.2\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\MS_Build_Runner_1.0.2\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes: you specified an invalid build configuration or the custom MSBuild analysis targets were not imported. 
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Post-processor 1.0.2.0
Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
10:21:04.257  Creating a summary markdown file...
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
ERROR: Execution of MSBuild SonarQube Runner failed (exit code 1)
```

The plugin installs itself int he tools subfolder of jenkins. But, looking in the project workspace, I can see a folder called .sonar that appears to have all the correct files and targets etc in it.

Any ideas on why the build is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MSBuild 12 at least (version 14, shipping with VS 2015 will give you more accurate analysis results with version 1.1 of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild & C# Plugin 4.4).

The `ImportsBefore` targets are not deployed for MSBuild 4.0 - which is why no information is being collected during your MSBuild execution. We're not going to add support for MSBuild 4.0 or earlier versions.

Note that in the upcoming SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1 version, the error message mentioning `ProjectInfo.xml` has been largely improved to let you know about the potential root causes: See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-180

Comment: Thanks Dinesh. I had installed MSBuild 14.0 but hadn't updated my jenkins build to use it... so it was still using the 4.0 build.